# Regular expression in Rails that matches an empty string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I am using the following regex to match a valid email address:
`/\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i`

How do I update this match a valid email address on an empty string?

I tried doing an "or" with `^$` but that did not do the trick.

Comment: you mean matching either a valid email OR an empty string?

Comment: Make the pattern optional - `/\A(?:[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+)?\z/i`

Comment: Also, maybe all you need is `allow_blank => true`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Or possibly better, convert empty strings to `nil` and `:allow_nil => true` so that you only have one missing value.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex for validating email

```
/\A\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+\z/i
```